# How to send ajax get request to WooCommerce rest API in localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using the Woocommerce Rest API. I can send a get request using **Postman** to the live site that uses `https` but I am currently using xampp for localhost server and I cannot connect to my localhost server.

But if I use **OAuth 1.0** in Postman and enter my woocommerce key and secret the URL becomes 
`http://localhost/mywebsite/wp-json/wc/v2/orders/12345?oauth_consumer_key=ck_my_key123&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1531881865&oauth_nonce=CxWcdh&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=fjfjosl12=`

The initial form of the URL before the request was `http://localhost/mywebsite/wp-json/wc/v2/orders/12345`

Now I want to send a jquery ajax getting the request to my localhost server with OAuth 1.0

```
  j('#getlatestorder').click(function() {

    debugger

    j.ajax({

      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost/mywebsite/wp-json/wc/v2/orders/12345?oauth_consumer_key=ck_my_key123&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1531881865&oauth_nonce=CxWcdh&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=fjfjosl12=',
      cache: false,
      data: {
        format: 'json'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('Order Received');
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr,status,error) {

      },
      complete: function() {
      }

    });

  });
```

I am receiving a `401 (Unauthorized)` error for the code above but I can connect in Postman.

Do you know if there is anything I can update with my jquery code? Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: your authorized signature doesn't matched. [DOC](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-http). Re-check your signature generation process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running woocommerce rest api locally then just add `s` to your `http` request so i think it will run smoothly.

Below is the url it should have for local :

```
`https://localhost/mywebsite/wp-json/wc/v2/orders/12345?oauth_consumer_key=ck_my_key123&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1531881865&oauth_nonce=CxWcdh&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=fjfjosl12=`
```

Comment: This is how you can proceed step by step for Oauth1 : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213006/how-to-use-oauth-authentication-with-rest-api-via-curl-commands/239873